# Applescript Copy file to a new folder

Tags: file, copy, applescript, directory

I need to create an AppleSript that will copy specified files from one folder to a newly created folder.

These files need to be specified in the AppleScript editor so something like:

```
start

fileToBeMoved = "Desktop/Test Folder 1/test.doc"
newfoldername = "Test Folder 2"

make newfolder and name it 'newfoldername'
copy 'fileToBeMoved' to 'newfolder'

end
```

Answer (score 13):

Generally:

```
tell application "Finder"
  make new folder at alias "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:" with properties {name:"Test Folder 2"}
  copy file "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:Test Folder 1:test.doc" to folder "Macintosh HD:Users:user:Desktop:Test Folder 2"
end tell
```

You can add variable names that represent POSIX files and paths.

Obviously the colon character (:) is a reserved character for folder- and filenames.

```
set desktopFolder to "Macintosh HD/Users/user/Desktop/"
set desktopFdrPosix to quoted form of POSIX path of desktopFolder
set newFolderName to "Test Folder 2"
set destinationFdrPosix to quoted form of desktopFdrPosix & POSIX file newFolderName
set sourceFilename to "Test Folder 1/test.doc"
set sourceFnPosix to quoted form of desktopFdrPosix & POSIX file sourceFilename

tell application "Finder"
  make new folder at alias desktopFdrPosix with properties {name:newFolderName}
  copy file sourceFnPosix to folder destinationFdrPosix
end tell
```

You may also want to add error checking if the destination folder already exists.

Comment: What do I need to change to copy to a folder on a mounted SMB file share? I have the folder "Movies" on a share mounted at `/Volumes/Video`. I tried creating a `quoted form of POSIX path` for `Video`, `Video/Movies`, `/Volumes/Video`, and `/Volumes/Video/Movies`, for both `copy file` and `duplicate file`, with either `to folder` or `to disk`. None of them worked. All give the error: `execution error: Finder got an error: Can't set folder` (or `disk`) `"'/Volumes/Video/Movies'" to file "'/Users/me/path/to/file.m4v'". (-10006)`

Answer (score 5):

The trick with AppleScript is that moving files is done using aliases.

More realistically it might be easier to make a shell script instead which can be run from AppleScript using `do shell script` if you're using Automator or something similar.

```
#!/bin/sh

fileToBeMoved="$HOME/Desktop/Test Folder 1/test.doc"
newFolderName="Test Folder 2"
mkdir "$newFolderName"
cp -a "$fileToBeMoved" "$newFolderName"
```

Comment: Its good to use this method over the applescript ones cause sometimes you might have permission issues and using this way helps then.

Comment: The downsides of this are: User won't see a progress bar if the copy takes longer. User can't cancel, either, for the same reason. Supporting these operations with a shell command will be a lot harder than simply letting the Finder do it. Downside of Applescripting the Finder, though: If the user chooses to use a replacement "Finder" app, the Applescript operation may fail (not sure about this, probably depends on how well the replacement is written).

Comment: Another plus for using the Finder: If the destination item exists, the user will be asked to replace or not.

Answer (score 3):

```
set home_path to path to home folder as string
set work_folder to alias (home_path & "AutomationAppleScript:ScreenShots:")
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate every file of work_folder to folder "Archive" of home
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for copying to a mounted network volume:

```
    mount volume "afp://compname.local/mountpoint"
    tell application "Finder"
      duplicate file "MyTextFile.txt" of folder "Documents" of home to disk "mountpoint"
      eject "mountpoint"
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a sync you're looking for you can run the following shell script in your AppleScript:

`rsync -a /Users/username/folderToBeCopiedFrom /Volumes/folderToBeCopiedTo/`

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "Finder"
    make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"folder"}
    duplicate POSIX file "/usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html" to result
end tell

POSIX file ((system attribute "HOME") & "/Documents" as text)
tell application "Finder" to result

tell application "Finder" to duplicate (get selection) to desktop replacing yes

-- these are documented in the dictionary of System Events
path to home folder
POSIX path of (path to documents folder)
path to library folder from user domain
path to desktop folder as text

-- getting files as alias list is faster
tell application "Finder"
    files of entire contents of (path to preferences folder) as alias list
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I used Chealions shell script solution. Don't forget to make your script file executable with:
`sudo chmod u+x scriptFilename`

Also remove the space between the `=` sign in the variable assignments. Wouldn't work with the spaces, for example: `newFolderName="Test Folder 2"`

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to do it is as below says

```
set home_path to path to home folder as string
set work_folder to alias (home_path & "AutomationAppleScript:ScreenShots:")
tell application "Finder"
    duplicate every file of work_folder to folder "Archive" of home
end tell
```