# Automation of Xcode project for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova, automation

I did 4 iphone application for different different categories of industry. Now I want to make more application for same category. So I want to know about how to make an iPhone project using any other scripting .. eg.. applescrippting, command line tool etc.
I also want to know about:

1. how to create new project using scripting?
2. how to copy file of other project in new project?
3. how to compile and make .ipa file using scripting.

Please any scripting guru and other iOS developer help me to know about this.

Can any one help me to create same project using scripting with different name

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to make the 'same project' but with a different name, why not set up a new Target in Xcode.

- Click your projects header
- Click on Add Target in the pane on the right

This will allow you to build and archive a different App, but keeping the same codebase. This way you do not need to worry about having duplicate code sets. NB: If you want each App to perform different functions then this isn't the best approach, but judging by your final line this is probably the right approach to suggest.

Comment: yes this is good way for making more same project but i have to change web service address and other code sign to release so i think i have to try script which i mention in my answer for making new project and change webservice address and assign code sign ...  
Thnk for your reply...

Comment: Not necessarily, a clean way to do this would be to build your webservice addresses into a plist file (rather than hard code them, this is bad practice anyway!), and have a different file assigned to each target. It's also possible to change the code signing on a per target basis.

Comment: You could additionally define preprocessor macros in Build Settings to segregate sections of code or web service addresses (which you intend to change) by differentiating them using ur custom defined macros. With that done you could then use `#if defined (TARGET_MACRO_1)
// Some web address for target 1
#else
// Some web address for target 2
#endif` .HTH.

Comment: @Sammio2 Thank you for your kind answer ... can you give one example of that to use webservice list in two plist ans using them in 2 targets//.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this blog - http://tmblr.co/Z7_TitY4veew
The section **Automating Build Uploads to TestFlight from Xcode** 
will give you an idea on how to prepare a build and upload it anywhere like TestFlight.

This thread on Stackoverflow should give you an idea on how to copy files -
[Applescript Copy file to a new folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902342/applescript-for-a-newbie-copy-file-to-a-new-folder)

Comment: i check testflight but i think it is use for run on device and my question is for making new project using scripting and make some change in that project.

Comment: Oh, that suggestion is the answer for your question                       - 3. how to compile and make .ipa file using scripting.